# Select records until the value gets repeated

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a hierarchy of 3 tables (Table1, Table2 and Table3).
The user can select a record from Table1 which then will return all the records from Table2 and then from Table3 and the user will see the records from table3. I need to leave out of the select the records from Table3 that already got selected from the previous record set of Table2.

[image: Tables]

So,  it should return only 3 elements with ProdID's 1,2 and 3 from Table3 plus the SortNr of table2 (if duplicate then the min from Table2). Example in Table3 "Sausage" comes twice, so it should return the SortNr of Table2 of the Min T2ID.

I tried with:

```
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t3.T1ID, t3.ProdID ORDER BY t3.T1ID, t3.ProdID > 1
```

to get the recors I need but without success.

I need to get the records as follow:
[image: table2]

**Edit:**

```
Select t3.nProdID, 
       t3.SortNr as nDetSort, 
       t3.Name as DetName, 
       t2.Name, 
       t2.SortNr, 
       t3.T2ID, 
       t2.T1ID, 
       t1.Name as MenuName, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t3.T1ID, t3.ProdID ORDER BY t3.T1ID, t2.T2ID, t3.ProdID > 1 then 'duplicates' else 'first occurance' end
  from Table1 t1, 
       Table2 t2, 
       table3 t3 
 where t1.ID = t2.T1ID and t2.T1ID = t3.T1ID and t2.T2ID = t3.T2ID
```

I managed to get the records I wanted by adding the t2.T2ID in the order by. But there is one thing I need to do. For the duplicated values I want to check if a specific column has a specific value, if not then get the min record from Table2 with the min T2ID value.

Comment: Please show some sample data and include the complete SQL you have tried.

Comment: I have added the SQL in the question @BrianLeach

Comment: @BrianLeach I got it, I have to to the right order by. But there is one thing I need to do. For the duplicated values I want to check if a specific column has a specific value, if not then get the min record from Table2 with the min T2ID value.